# Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object Worksheet - ACE OLEDB

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

I am trying to do a Join on 3 tables in Excel through VBA using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. Having lots of issues trying to get the query to run. At this point I get the following error:

`Run-time error '-2147217865 (800040e37)':`

`The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'CustomSheetName1$A$1:$AV$6027'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'CustomSheetName1$A$1:$AV$6027' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.`

The source file is created in the same sub and saved to the macro root folder located locally in `C:\Users\localuser\Documents\MacroFolder\`. I have full access to the file.

When run the connection string shows as:

`"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\localuser\Documents\MacroFolder\Book4.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"`

Extract of sub below. I have obfuscated the field names and only included code I thought was relevant. Can add more and clarify further if required. Code breaks at the last line when executing the query.

```
Dim wbTarget As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add

Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets.Add(After:=wbTarget.Sheets(wbTarget.Sheets.Count))
wsTarget.Name = "CustomSheetName1"

varFilePathElements = Split(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\")
strFileName = varFilePathElements(UBound(varFilePathElements))
Dim strWBTargetFullFileName As String
strWBTargetFullFileName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Path, "strfilename", "") & "\" & wbTarget.Name & ".xlsx"

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strWBTargetFullFileName _
    & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

strSQL = "SELECT " _
            & "sh1.company_name, " _
            & "sh1.company_type, " _
            & "sh1.customer_no, " _
            & "sh1.fk1, " _
            & "SUM(sh3.total_stat) as total_stat, " _
            & "FROM ( [CustomSheetName1" & wbTarget.Sheets("CustomSheetName1").UsedRange.Address & "] sh1 " _
            & "LEFT JOIN [CustomSheetName2" & wbTarget.Sheets("CustomSheetName2").UsedRange.Address & "] sh2 " _
            & "ON sh2.fk1 = sh1.fk1 ) " _
            & "LEFT JOIN [CustomSheetName3" & wbTarget.Sheets("CustomSheetName3").UsedRange.Address & "] sh3 " _
            & "ON sh3.fk2 = sh2.fk2 AND sh3.fk3 = sh2.fk3 " _
            & "GROUP BY sh1.customer_no, sh1.company_name, sh1.company_type, sh1.fk1 " _
            & "ORDER BY total_stat"

wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value2 = strSQL
wbTarget.SaveAs (strWBTargetFullFileName)
wbTarget.Close

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Regards,

Comment: Can you share the table names in your access db with us?

Comment: I am not using an access db. I am trying to use the OLE DB driver to do a join of 3 tables in 3 sheets in a workbook. Hope this clarifies further.

Comment: I see. Then try putting "!" at the end of your sheet names like "CustomSheetName1!"

Comment: I recall trying this form of regular Excel naming convention. Retried it and got `'CustomSheetName1!&A1:AV6027' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.` Any other suggestions. Regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When reading Excel worksheets via ADO, the $ sign is appended to the end of the worksheet name, like this:

`SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]`

Using the absolute range address adds extra $ signs that cause the worksheet name to be interpreted incorrectly. You need to use non-absolute range addresses to stop this happening. Adding some parameters to `UsedRange.Address` can fix this:

`[CustomSheetName1$" & wbTarget.Sheets("CustomSheetName1").UsedRange.Address(False, False) & "]`

Comment: I tried this already and did not fix it. I tried it again on your suggestion and still errored out. On review, finally figured out that I was putting `&` instead of `$`... on 2 different occasions!! ;p Now the query is running, though with other errors that I will try to resolve or post another question. Thanks for your answer. Regards,